# UITableViewCell shadows overlay

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

I have a table view with cells.
Overlaying shadows is done, but that looks not like I wanted.
My shadow white round rectangles should stay white. And shadows should overlay below white rectangles. Any suggestions on how to achieve expected behavior?

[image]

I added shadow as a separate subview

```swift
class ShadowView: UIView {
    
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            setupShadow()
        }
    }
    
    private func setupShadow() {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowRadius = 40
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 10)
        layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath
    }
}
```

and then

```swift
let shadowView = ShadowView()        
addSubview(shadowView)
```

I wanted something like this. White rectangles are completely white.

[image]

Comment: Ok. This is getting confusing. Which one is the `ShadowView`? Black or white view? If it's white, why don't you add the shadıw to table view cell's layer?

Comment: Hierarchy is UITableViewCell -> ShadowView -> MyContainerView. MyContainerView is a rounded white view, that contains black rectangles).

Comment: @IvanVavilov - *"shadows should overlay below white rectangles"* -- it's a little difficult to know what you are really going for. Can you create an image that looks like what you ***want*** (as opposed to the image that looks like what you don't want)?

Comment: @DonMag updated the original post.

Comment: @IvanVavilov - are your cells all the same height? Or will the heights vary based on the contents? For example, is it possible the "Seeing mom for Mother's Day" label may wrap onto multiple lines...

Comment: @DonMag dynamic cell height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as you are seeing, is that rows (cells) are separate **views**. If you allow an element to extend outside the cell, it will either overlap or underlap the adjacent views.

Here's a simple example to clarify...

Each cell has a `systemYellow` view that extends outside its frame on the top and bottom:

[image]

If we use `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect the layout, it looks something like this:

[image]

As we can see, because of the initial z-order, each cell is covering the part of the systemYellow view that is extending up and the part that is extending down overlaps the next cell.

As we scroll a bit, cells are re-drawn at different z-order positions (based on how the tableView re-uses them):

[image]

Now we see that some of the systemYellow views overlap the row above, some overlap the row below, and some overlap both.

Inspecting the layout shows us the cells' z-order positions:

[image]

If we want to maintain the z-order so that none of the systemYellow views overlap the cell below it, we can add a func to manipulate the z-order positions:

```
func updateLayout() -> Void {
    for c in tableView.visibleCells {
        tableView.bringSubviewToFront(c)
    }
}
```

and we need to call that whenever the tableView scrolls (and when the layout changes):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    updateLayout()
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    updateLayout()
}
```

So, the same thing is happening with your layout... the shadows are extending outside the frame of the cell, and either over- or under-lapping the adjacent cells.

If we start by using the same approach to manage the z-order of the cells, we can get this:

[image]

[image]

So, we're keeping the white rounded-rect views on top of the "shadow above." Of course, now we have the shadows overlapping the *bottom* of the view.

We can change the rectangle for the `.shadowPath` to avoid that:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    var r = bounds
    r.origin.y += 40
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: r, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath
}
```

and we get this output:

[image]

[image]

One more issue though -- if we use the default cell `.selectionStyle`, we get this:

[image]

which is probably not acceptable.

So, we can set the `.selectionStyle` to `.none`, and implement `setSelected` in our cell class. Here, I change the rounded-rect background and the text colors to make it extremely obvious:

[image]

Here is some example code -- no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections needed, so just assign the class of a new table view controller to `ShadowTableViewController` :

```
class ShadowView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowRadius = 40
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.cornerRadius = 12
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        var r = bounds
        r.origin.y += 40
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: r, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath
    }

}

class ShadowCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let shadowView = ShadowView()
    let topLabel = UILabel()
    let bottomLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        shadowView.backgroundColor = .white
        
        topLabel.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24.0)
        bottomLabel.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        bottomLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 8
        
        stack.addArrangedSubview(topLabel)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(bottomLabel)
        
        shadowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        shadowView.addSubview(stack)
        contentView.addSubview(shadowView)
        
        let mg = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            shadowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mg.topAnchor),
            shadowView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mg.leadingAnchor),
            shadowView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mg.trailingAnchor),
            shadowView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mg.bottomAnchor),
            
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shadowView.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shadowView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shadowView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shadowView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            
        ])
        
        contentView.clipsToBounds = false
        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.backgroundColor = .clear

        selectionStyle = .none
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        shadowView.backgroundColor = selected ? .systemBlue : .white
        topLabel.textColor = selected ? .white : .black
        bottomLabel.textColor = selected ? .white : .black
    }

}

class ShadowTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.register(ShadowCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "shadowCell")
    }

    func updateLayout() -> Void {
        for c in tableView.visibleCells {
            tableView.bringSubviewToFront(c)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        updateLayout()
    }
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateLayout()
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shadowCell", for: indexPath) as! ShadowCell
        c.topLabel.text = "Row: \(indexPath.row)"
        var s = "Description for row \(indexPath.row)"
        if indexPath.row % 3 == 1 {
            s += "\nSecond Line"
        }
        if indexPath.row % 3 == 2 {
            s += "\nSecond Line\nThirdLine"
        }
        c.bottomLabel.text = s
        return c
    }
    
}
```

Note: this is ***Example Code Only*** and should not be considered **Production Ready**.